# How do I change viewport alignment of newly created objects with a python command?

Tags: python, scripting, 3d-view, interface, customization

I'm making a custom pie menu with a pie editor addon and wanted to have some buttons with options that will let me change the default alignment of newly created objects from "world", "view" to "3d cursor" as I tend to change these options sometimes and don't want to open preferences window all the time I do. Can somebody tell me if there's a specific python command that will allow me to do that? I can't seem to find one.

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Answer:

In Python, the command to set the alignment is  `bpy.context.preferences.edit.object_align = 'VALUE'` where VALUE can be one of WORLD, VIEW, or CURSOR.

This will affect any objects added *after* you've made the change.

### Background:

The way to find such things in preferences is to enable *Developer Extras* in the *Interface* panel.  Then if you hover over the input field and right click you'll get a menu like this:

[image: right click menu]

If you select *Edit Source* it will make the source for that part of the UI available as text object.  You can go to the text editor and view the code.  You may have to use the dropdown to select the right file.  Here's the code for that field:

```
        flow.prop(edit, "object_align", text="Align To")
```

You have to do some decoding to get the proper name.  First you start with the `bpy.context.preferences` prefix.  The first argument of the prop field tells you that the field is in the `edit` properties.  The second argument tells you the name of the field.  Putting it all together you get `bpy.context.preferences.edit.object_align`.

If, as in this case, you don't know what values to assign, you can use the Python console to figure them out.  Before each line in the below sample, I manually set the field to one of the three options.  So the output below is the value you should use if you want that option.

```
>>> bpy.context.preferences.edit.object_align
'WORLD'

>>> bpy.context.preferences.edit.object_align
'VIEW'

>>> bpy.context.preferences.edit.object_align
'CURSOR'
```

### Bonus for reading this far:

Here's a very crude demonstration of a pie menu using this command:

```
import bpy
from bpy.types import Menu, Operator


class MY_MT_align(Menu):
    # bl_label is displayed at the center of the pie menu
    bl_label = 'Align Mode'
    bl_idname = 'MY_MT_Align'


    def draw(self, context):
        layout = self.layout
        pie = layout.menu_pie()
        pie.operator("my.align_world", icon = 'EVENT_A')
        pie.operator("my.align_view", icon = 'EVENT_B')
        pie.operator("my.align_cursor", icon = 'EVENT_C')



class MY_OT_align_world(Operator):
    bl_idname = 'my.align_world'
    bl_label = 'Align World'
    bl_description = "Set New object alignment to world"

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.context.preferences.edit.object_align = "WORLD"
        return {'FINISHED'}

class MY_OT_align_view(Operator):
    bl_idname = 'my.align_view'
    bl_label = 'Align View'
    bl_description = "Set New object alignment to view"

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.context.preferences.edit.object_align = "VIEW"
        return {'FINISHED'}

class MY_OT_align_cursor(Operator):
    bl_idname = 'my.align_cursor'
    bl_label = 'Align Cursor'
    bl_description = "Set New object alignment to 3D Cursor"

    def execute(self, context):
        bpy.context.preferences.edit.object_align = "CURSOR"
        return {'FINISHED'}

classes = [
    MY_OT_align_world,
    MY_OT_align_view,
    MY_OT_align_cursor,
    MY_MT_align,
]


def register():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.register_class(cls)


def unregister():
    for cls in classes:
        bpy.utils.unregister_class(cls)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    register()
    bpy.ops.wm.call_menu_pie(name = 'MY_MT_Align')
```

Comment: Thank you for your thorough answer, I am just starting to learn the API of blender after years of use. You saved me, I was looking for the method for quite a while and looked in the wrong direction. For some reason I thought it was somewhere in bpy.context.Preferences class, your answer cleared everything out for me and now the structure makes perfect sense! A new addition to my mega pie!

Comment: You're very welcome.  I'm glad I was able to help.  I look forward to seeing what you accomplish.  The Preferences settings take some getting used to, but now you've seen the organization you should have no trouble figuring out the rest of them.

Comment: I should add that the script at the end is using a big hammer.  You can do it with a single operator, if you give the operator a string property, set the string property differently in each operator entry in the menu and use it for the assignment.  But I wanted the crude version to not introduce too many concepts all at once.

Comment: Ooh, yeah. I figured that 3 operators for 3 methods with one command might be an overkill. Thank you for your help, you saved me lots of headache! :)

Comment: You can also directly modify the enum prop by adding `pie.prop(context.preferences.edit, "object_align")` to the pie `draw` method